# Why am I getting invalid numeric numeral using Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am using Carbon to get the number of years I've been in FL in a controller and it was working.  I came home and suddenly it doesn't work.  I don't know what could have changed.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class PageController extends BaseController {


    public function showAbout()
    {

        $livedInFl = Carbon::createFromDate(1997, 08, 15)->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y');
        $realtorFor = Carbon::createFromDate(2006, 03, 14)->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y');
        $grahamAge = Carbon::createFromDate(2011, 11, 29)->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y');

        return view('pages.about', array('grahamAge' => $grahamAge, 'livedInFl' => $livedInFl, 'realtorFor' => $realtorFor));
    }


}
```

I was using this in a blade view and it was showing "Chris has lived in Florida for 19 years" without problem.  Suddenly, I run it and I get:

```
FatalThrowableError in PageController.php line 12:
Parse error: Invalid numeric literal
```

I've Googled this error and can't find anything that could be the reason so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is valid.

Try next decision (remove 0):

```
$livedInFl = Carbon::createFromDate(1997, 8, 15)->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y');
$realtorFor = Carbon::createFromDate(2006, 3, 14)->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y');
```

Comment: Explanation.... a numeric value beginning with `0` is treated as octal by PHP, and `08` is not a valid octal number